# How to Enable SSL on Laravel Sail

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

I am using Laravel Sail and I am trying to share my site for testing. It works fine. The website can be accessed using the url generated from `sail share`. What I want to happen is to use SSL while sharing the test website.

I have tried searching around but I did not get the answer for this. I was only given links to another website but it does not help because Laravel Sail is using containers. If possible, a guide would be helpful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can find this information on https://beyondco.de/docs/expose/client/configuration

Apparantly this is default behaviour when you configure expose ([the underlying technique](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#sharing-your-site) of Laravel Sail) to use port 443.

Comment: I have read the documentation over and over but I am not sure how to integrate this with Laravel Sail. Do you have detailed instructions for this?

Comment: If you cannot make it work with the built in `share` (using expose) you might want to consider using `ngrok`. I can guarantee it works out of the box